# Parse Relation Query:How to Get Only one user from relation list

Tags: android, parse-platform

Hi there I'm new to parse, android and stackoverflow.com, here is my question 
I've two classes on parse one is "post" and other is "user" class. Anyone can like post and dislike post.
 I've created two relation column "whoLiked" and "whoDisliked" which points the list of users who has liked/disliked a specific post.
When I'm showing the post to the user I want the current User to like/dislike the post Only once which I've set properly.
But only thing I'm not getting is how can I fetch only currentuser from  thisPost object. 
I don't wanna fetch the list of user who liked this post I just want to know if current User has liked it or not.?

I'm new to stackoverflow.com plz ignore if any mistakes here. Thanks u all in advance.
Below is the query to fetch all the liker
    ParseObject post = ...

```
// create a relation based on the authors key
ParseRelation relation = book.getRelation("whoLiked");

// generate a query based on that relation
ParseQuery query = relation.getQuery();

query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
public void done(List<ParseObject> comments, ParseException e) {
    if (e == null) {
        // "user" is now a list of the user who liked 
    } else {
        // Something went wrong...
    }
}
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a constraint to check if the `objectId` is the same as the `currentUsers`'s `objectId`:

```
// create a relation based on the authors key
ParseRelation relation = book.getRelation("whoLiked");

// generate a query based on that relation
ParseQuery query = relation.getQuery();

// ADD CONSTRAINT HERE:
ParseUser currentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
query.whereEqualTo("objectId", currentUser.getObjectId());

query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
public void done(List<ParseObject> comments, ParseException e) {
    if (e == null) {
        // "user" is now a list of the user who liked 
    } else {
        // Something went wrong...
    }
}
});
```

Comment: Thank u kriz it worked for me, when I tried using whereEqualsTo( ) on my own it was not working but now it is working smoothly. Thank u

Comment: Thanks to you and stack overflow first time I asked the question and got the best result.